# What is the highest temperature, ambient pressure type-1 superconductor as of 2022?

Tags: conductivity

I was curious about the highest known Tc for type 1 superconductors.

[This](http://www.superconductors.org/Type1.htm) list suggests lead near 7K is as good as it gets for type-1 superconductors but I wonder if that is true given the current state of the art.

Comment: Just a warning, some aspects of that site are... contentious, especially the high Tc claims.

Comment: Somewhat confusingly some compounds exhibit both type 1 and type 2 behaviour (MgB2 for example). It has a Tc of ~39 K and has at least some type 1 character.